# Asterisk - executing agi script if call is not answerd?

Tags: asterisk, agi

Here is context CH1 which i want to call from .call file

```
[CH1]
exten=>9367,1,Playback(welcome);
same =>  n,Agi(agi://localhost/openlock.agi)
same =>  n,Background(CH1_WAVE1)
same =>  n,Hangup()
```

my .call file look like this

```
Channel: DAHDI/1/somemumber
CallerID:xyz
MaxRetries: 3
RetryTime: 40
WaitTime: 25
Context:CH1
Extension: 9367
Priority: 1
```

So my problem is this if one does not answer the call, my AGI script will not get execute, so is there any way to execute my AGI script if the call is not answered after 3 retries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way do it for 3 retries.
But posible do for each retry.

In call file change channel to Local/somenumber@dialout/n

Create context

```
[dialout]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(DAHDI/1/${EXTEN},,g)
exten => _X.,2,Goto(${DIALSTATUS},1)
exten => BUSY,1,AGI(busy.agi)
exten => CONGESTION,1,AGI(fail.agi)
exten => FAILED,1,AGI(fail.agi)
exten => NOANSWER,1,AGI(noanaswer.agi)
```

Also i higly NOT recomend create dialling if you are not guru in asterisk. Use opensource engines. It have REALY allot of issues you never think about.

Comment: thanks , it got worked ,it was just for learning purpose ,so no problem in testing anything new :P. btw can u suggest any good books that covers advance features of asterisk ?

Comment: "Asterisk the future of telephony". "Asterisk™: The Definitive Guide"

Comment: very nice info and it helped me alot.

Comment: Common, that info present in default extensions.conf.sample